# How can I get a column to return value of another column?? help

Tags: list, microsoft

i am creating an employee contact list for my company. One of the columns is "Departments" (a choice column n=5). In each Department, there are several teams. Because Employees will need to enter/update their information, I made 5 "Teams" choice columns so that if an employee select their department, only the teams titles in that department appear. so far I am good.

Now my issue is, because those are five distinct columns, visualizing the information is not the best. I would like to be able to see all Team's title values in one column instead of 5 different columns (and avoid the blanks).

**Summary**

Column 1: Department - choice (text) - a, b, c, d, e;

Column 2: Team A - choice (text) - aa, bb, cc, ee;

Column 3: Team B - choice (text) - aa, bb, cc, ee;

Column 4: Team C - choice (text) - aa, bb, cc, ee;

Column 5: Team D - choice (text) - aa, bb, cc, ee;

Column 5: Team E - choice (text) - aa, bb, cc, ee;
what I want:

***What I want***

**Column 6:**

if (column 1)== a, show text value of what was chosen in (column 2), if (column 1) == b, show text value of what was chosen in (column 3), etc.

I am new to this so any help is much appreciated. i am using MS2016. my goal is to have this as an app.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a calculated column and use the ["IF" function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-0a4ad187-dba3-48ae-abe9-bbe3aa6aebca).

The formula would need to be something like

```
=IF([Department]="A",[Team A],IF([Department]="B",[Team B],IF([Department]="C",[Team C],IF([Department]="D",[Team D],IF([Department]="E",[Team E],"")))))
```